# Why does polymerization reaction between amino acids produce different products as compared to the reaction between amine and carboxylic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Elaborate:

Amino Acid A + Amino Acid B -> Peptide chain + H20

Amine + Carboxylic Acid -> Salt

Why do they have different outcomes when breaking it down they are both the reaction between the 2 function groups: carboxyl(-COOH) and amino (-NH2)

Answer (score 2):

These two cases are not all that different.

In mild conditions amines + carboxylic acids end up producing salts. **So do amino acids**. Mind you, there is no need to use two of them, for each amino acid already has $\ce{-COOH}$ and $\ce{-NH2}$. In a way, each amino acid is a salt in itself.

If you remove water, then amino acids produce compounds with $\ce{-CONH}-$ link. **So do amines with carboxylic acids**. You must have heard of [nylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon_66); 
indeed, it is a polymer, not unlike peptides.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that $\rightarrow$ means two different things in the reactions you've written.

You can't just add two amino acids together and get a peptide. That's the *overall* transformation, but it takes place via several steps and requires other reagents or catalysts.

If you just mix two amino acids together, e.g., a sample of a single amino acid, you get the second reaction. The case of an amino acid, it doesn't quite make a salt because the acid and base are on the same molecule. Instead, you get a [zwitterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion). And indeed, amino acids do exists as zwitterions in solution at physiological pH.